# Animating div appearance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I don't know how to add animation for opening and closing. I know that this script is not so good, but i didn't found any other menu scripts, where would be possible automatic closing when click outside of dropped block. Thank you. Here is the code

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.55s;
  animation-duration: 0.55s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you clarify? On the snippet the submenu is closing when I click outside of the menu. That's the functionality you're after, no?

Comment: What sort of animation are you looking to have happen? Slide up/down? Fade in/out?

Comment: If you remove your `display: none;` in `.dropdown-content`, it works

Comment: And i would not interact with elements under block

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the kind of transition you want, but you can achieve most of them using CSS alone.

In my example below I used fade in/out. You had already defined a `transition`, but the syntax needed to be amended to work with the `opacity` property. Also, you'd set `animation` which wasn't required. You also set the `min-height` of the element which makes it immediately disappear when the class is toggled off, so I removed that.

Here's a working example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      dropdowns[i].classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that you can make your JS more succinct by using `forEach()` to loop over the dropdowns:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content"), function(dd) {
    dd.classList.remove('show');
  });
}
```

However be aware that this won't work in any browser that doesn't support ES2015, eg. IE8 or lower.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Also thanks for better succinct js code.

Comment: So i found a minus of this method. When opacity is 0, i can not interact with elements under block.

Comment: True. If you need that try animating the `height` instead.